# Determine a resistor's value in a circuit with an N-type MOS-FET transistor

Tags: mosfet, resistors

In a circuit involving an N-type MOS-FET I am to determine the value of resistor \$R_2\$

Now in order to solve this I need to know what  \$V_{DD}\$ represents, is that the voltage relative to node D in the circuit or the lowest part of the circuit? What does this subindex stand for? I guess it can be safely assumed that \$V_S\$ is not zero, since it isn't grounded on the diagram.

The condensator C is so big that it acts as a short circuit for AC signals (as I understand it C can be ignored for solving this).

\$v_D\$ = \$V_{DQ}\$ = 8.0 V in this situation.

We are to show that \$R_2\$ = 20.6 kohms. Now I'm at a loss, because of the confusion regarding the voltages and how this circuit works. Suggestions are highly appreciated!

Threshold voltage is right under 2.40 volts.

[image: N-type MOS-FET circuit, determine resistor]

Comment: VDD is just a label. It is customary to label the highest voltage power supply VDD (or VCC). In the circuit shown, VDD is referenced to GND. GND is not shown, but you probably have to assume that the bottom node is ground. In other words, you have to assume that VDD is 16V referenced to the source pin of the MOSFET. I don't see that this is enough information to do the problem, but hopefully it helps you a little. Maybe was the threshold voltage of the MOSFET specified?

Comment: yea threshold voltage is 2.40 volts.
So you're saying that VDD is referenced to what would be the S part on our diagram? Are you sure, because when we say VDS it is the voltage drop from D to S, I'd assume it would be the same for VDD, but I'm not certain, guess you are correct here.

Comment: The convention of calling the highest voltage in a MOSFET circuit VDD is so common that I would even say it is universal or ubiquitous. Just like calling the zero reference voltage "GND."

Comment: VDS would be a difference of voltages between DRAIN and SOURCE. VDD is a difference of voltages between DRAIN and GND. Source isn't always connected to GND...

Comment: This is good to know, what I thought yea.

Comment: Hmm so VDD is referenced to VS which we assume is grounded, but if VS is not zero (grounded) than VDD is different than the sum of the voltage drops over Rd and from drain to source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For \$V_D=8\rm{V}\$, the quiescent current (through the MOSFET) is \$I_D=\frac{16\rm{V}-8\rm{V}}{1.2\rm{k\Omega}}=6.67\rm{mA}\$. Knowing that the transistor must be in saturation, you use the equation for saturation drain current:
$$I_D=\frac{k}{2}(V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2$$
Of course, transconductance parameter \$k\$ and threshold voltage \$V_{TH}\$ must be known. From this equation, you can solve for \$V_{GS}\$, which here is equal to \$V_G\$, and, in combination with the voltage divider equation \$V_G=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_{DD}\$, you can solve for \$R_2\$.

Comment: i guess we can solve for k, since you found Id, cause k is not given.

Comment: @Mollart: You claim that your assignment is to *show* that \$R_2\$ is \$20.6\rm{k\Omega}\$, but you can't do this without knowing what \$k\$ is (because you need to know \$k\$ in order to know \$V_G\$). If you don't know \$k\$, then this is an unsolvable problem.

Comment: Is any other information given that would allow you to calculate k? It has been a while since I studied IC design in University, but I seem to remember that there are some dimensions and process constants that you can use to calculate k.

Comment: @mkeith: \$k=\mu C_{ox}W/L\$, where \$\mu\$ is electron mobility, \$C_{ox}\$ is the gate capacitance per unit area (\$=\epsilon /t_{ox}\$), and W and L are the width and length, respectively. So if he's given these things, then yes he can solve for \$k\$. However, considering that this circuit design is not appropriate for ICs but rather for discrete design, it is unlikely that these parameters are given. Assuming it's a real device, it would be much easier just to measure it or look it up in the datasheet.

Comment: @ZekeR, good point about it not being an IC design. But since it seems to be a class assignment, I doubt there is a datasheet. Probably some misunderstanding somewhere along the line.

Comment: aaah sorry was a bit overloaded when writing this post, I forgot to include the voltage at the gate (found by extrapolation on the characteristic sheet) to be 2.73 volts. If this is used the formula you found returns 20.6 kohms for R2, which is exactly what we where after. Thanks a lot guys!